# R CMD recognize only some commands

Tags: r, cmd, path, config

I am testing the R CMD command but I can't get it working for the `config` command while the `open` command, for instance, works. I have set the Path in the environment variables as recommended.

`PATH=c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin;`etc.

When I type the `R CMD config --help` I receive the infamous `'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I read that a possible issue may have been the space in `Program Files` but I double quoted it in the environmental variables and the issue remained.

I have noticed though that when I navigate to `c:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin` I find the two folders `x64` and `i386` and outside of those there is a `config.sh` file. May this be a hint for a solution?

Comment: In my PATH, I have `\x64`, which is where the R.exe is. What is `config --help` suppose to accomplish?

Comment: Is just testing whether the `config` command is working. I also tried to add the `\x64` bit but nothing changed.

Comment: When I type `R CMD config`, I get a cygwin warning (as usual) and the a list of options and variables.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like to see but instead I obtain `'sh' is not recognized` etc.

Comment: Perhaps you need to get your cygwin in order? Or perhaps you have several definitions in your PATH that lead to different R.exe files?

Comment: The ones I showed are the only calls to R in the PATH. What do you mean by "get cygwin in order"? I am sorry but I am not very knowledgeable.

Comment: Cygwin brings you a number of linux tools to windows, including sh.exe, which you appear to be missing. https://www.cygwin.com/